# Infinite execution of tasks for nodejs application

Tags: javascript, node.js, io

Suppose I have code, like this

```
function execute() {
    var tasks = buildListOfTasks();
    // ...
}
```

`buildListOfTask` creates array of functions. Functions are async, might issue HTTP requests or/and perform db operations.

If tasks list appears empty or all tasks are executed, I need to repeat same `execute` routine again. And again, in say "infinite loop". So, it's daemon like application.

I could quite understand how to accomplish that in sync-world, but bit confused how to make it possible in node.js async-world.

Comment: Helpful link, perhaps https://github.com/creationix/step

Comment: Use the jQuery idea of deferred objects. I think there's even a Javascript library that mimics this

Comment: @AlexWayne yes, it helps, but not completely. I'm familiar with libs like that (personally using async). I bit more confused how to "loop" the operation.

Comment: what's wrong with setTimeout?o_O

Comment: @EldarDjafarov like, setTimeout(execute, 100) ?

Comment: Ian beat me too it, differed objects is a good approach.  The idea is to have another object manage the queue of tasks by having the tasks call a function to let this object how they completed.  When the queue-managing-object sees all the tasks are complete it can call `execute` again.

Comment: yes function execute() { var tasks = buildListOfTasks(); if(tasks.length ===0) {return setTimeout(execute,100)} /***/}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) and it's queue object.

```
function runTask(task, callback) {
    //dispatch a single asynchronous task to do some real work
    task(callback);
}
//the 10 means allow up to 10 in parallel, then start queueing
var queue = async.queue(runTask, 10);

//Check for work to do and enqueue it
function refillQueue() {
  buildListOfTasks().forEach(function (task) {
    queue.push(task);
  });
}    

//queue will call this whenever all pending work is completed
//so wait 100ms and check again for more arriving work
queue.drain = function() {
  setTimeout(refillQueue, 100);
};

//start things off initially
refillQueue();
```

Comment: that looks really close to what I need.. will try!

Answer (score 1):

If you're already familiar with libraries like `async`, you can use the `execute()` as the final callback to restart the tasks:

```
function execute(err) {
    if (!err) {
        async.series(buildListOfTasks(), execute);
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: is that possible to get stackoverflow exception with such code?

Comment: Do to these being asynchronous calls even though execute will be invoked many times, the stack gets reset on every async callback so you won't overflow it.

Comment: However, you need to actually look at the `err` argument and not just blindly keep firing off async.series in a tight loop if it is throwing errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use async.js, probably the parallel function. https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel

In the global callback, just call execute to make a recursive call.

```
async.parallel(tasks,
    function(err, results){
        if(!err) execute();
    }
);
```

Comment: Queue is a bit safer than this because of tho maximum concurrency limit. If a call to buildListOfTasks returned 800 DB queries, this could bring your DB to its knees, for example.